# The act of carrying out a task first, earlier than in its scheduled order

Tags: single-word-requests, gerunds, abstract-nouns

Suppose you need to carry out several tasks in a certain order (which may be an order of priorities, or of supposed dependencies, or just arbitrary). Is there a word, preferably a gerund, for the act of choosing one of these tasks, which is not the first, and carrying it out before all the others?

I mean *both* of these actions together, not just one of them. So, **rescheduling** won't do, because it doesn't imply actually carrying anything out.

Comment: Could you give an example sentence please? _Putting the [cart before the horse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cart_before_the_horse)_ comes to mind...

Comment: *The act of choosing to carry out a task earlier than its scheduled order?* - Captain Sully *had prerogative* to make an *executive decision* to *preemptively* start the APU.

Comment: @Mazura See my comment at Jason Bassford below.

Comment: The idea is to move an item in a queue ahead of the others.

Answer (score 2):

By choosing a task that's out of sequence, you are **preempting** the next task in order in favour of the other one.

From Merriam-Webster's definition of [preempt](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/preempt):

> preempted; preempting; preempts
>
> **3 a** : to replace with something considered to be of greater value or priority : take precedence over
>
> • the program did not appear, having been *preempted* by a baseball game
> —Robert MacNeil

**Update:** As per a comment, be careful to note the usage of the different verb forms.

> 1. X *preempts* Y.
> 2. X is *preempting* Y.
> 3. X *preempted Y*.

However, with a preposition, the subject and object are switched:

> Y is *preempted* ***by*** X.

This answer, in the initial sentence, was careful to select the *-ing* form of the verb as the particular answer to the question, and did not use a preposition.

Comment: Can I also be said to be preempting all tasks before the one I'm carrying out first?

Comment: @einpoklum Unless you are working on tasks in parallel, the current one effectively preempts everything else. (Although the implication is that it's only preempting whatever would normally have been done instead of it.)

Comment: -1 Preempted is the one that has **not** been done, not the one that has been done out of turn.

Comment: @Kris: Agree with your comment, but not with the -1, since the act is **preempting** regardless of which of the tasks has been preempted.

Comment: @Kris Your assertion only makes sense if *preempted* is followed by the preposition *by*.

Answer (score 0):

**out of turn** AmE  [collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/out-of-turn)

> not in proper sequence or order

Answer (score 0):

Jump the gun:

According to [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary-cambridge-org.cdn.ampproject.org/v/s/dictionary.cambridge.org/amp/english/jump-the-gun?amp_js_v=a2&amp_gsa=1&usqp=mq331AQCCAE%3D#referrer=https://www.google.com&amp_tf=From%20%251%24s&ampshare=https%3A%2F%2Fdictionary.cambridge.org%2Fdictionary%2Fenglish%2Fjump-the-gun), in American English, *to jump the gun* is to act too soon or before the right time.

Answer (score -3):

I'd call it "to ***upprioritize***" ("*upprioritizing*") something.

The idea here is to move an item in a queue ahead of the others -- advance, or move forward.

To prioritize is to set down the order of items in the queue. (Also used to mean to increase the priority level).

To deprioritize is to reduce its priority level -- moving it back.

To up- or down- prioritize would be to raise or lower the priority level of an item -- advancing (bringing it forward) or moving it back in the queue.

HTH.

Comment: No, that's not it. Changing priorities does not mean you've done anything. Also, like I said in the question, the tasks are not necessarily ordered by priority.

Comment: @einpoklum You are obviously confused. Without first an order, how can you do something out of turn? Btw, changing the priority could include acting upon it.

Comment: Finally, "doing out of turn" would be your only possible option.

Comment: *Upprioritize* is not a real word. And suddenly choking to death in the middle of checking off items on a shopping list does not mean that you add saving your life to the list. It means you interrupt doing anything involving shopping in order to deal with the crisis. Once that's done, you return to the list. Some item *on* the list that suddenly requires immediate attention has the same effect. You deal with it at once, then return to the list (and check it off as it is no longer required). The first item was never moved from the top, it was simply superseded.

Comment: @JasonBassford What happens when superseded? The top item stays at the top, eh?  I'm not for extending the argument.